# Is an attribute protected if initialized as public but setters & getters treat it as protected?

Tags: python, oop

While learning the basics of object oriented programming in Python, I came across something I cannot search effectively to find matching keywords:

I wrote validation checks for a basic class `Course`, which has a protected attribute `_level`. The getters and setters treat this as a protected attribute. The validation makes sure `self._level` are between 0 and 100.

- But the validation checks in the setter are evaded:

```py
class Course:
    
    def __init__(self, level=None):        
        self._level = level if level else 0
        
    @property
    def level(self):
        return self._level
    
    @level.setter
    def level(self, value):        
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('The value of level must be of type int.')        
        if value < 0:
            self._level = 0
        elif value > 100:
            self._level = 100
        else:
            self._level = value

###
courses = [Course(), Course(10), Course(-10), Course(150)]
for c in courses:
    print(c.level)
>>> 0
>>> 10
>>> -10
>>> 150
```

- I then change the initialization from a protected `self._level` to a public attribute `self.level`. My setters and getters still refer to a protected attribute `self._level`.

```py
class Course:
    
    def __init__(self, level=None):        
        self.level = level if level else 0
        
    @property
    def level(self):
        return self._level
    
    @level.setter
    def level(self, value):        
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('The value of level must be of type int.')        
        if value < 0:
            self._level = 0
        elif value > 100:
            self._level = 100
        else:
            self._level = value
        
courses = [Course(), Course(10), Course(-10), Course(150)]
for c in courses:
    print(c.level)
>>> 0
>>> 10
>>> 0
>>> 100
```

I was surprised that not only does the class realize it is the same attribute, but now my validations are implemented!

How does Python reconcile `self.level` with `self._level`, and why must I initialize it as a public attribute in order for my validations to kick in?

Comment: A single underscore is just a naming convention, it has no special meaning to Python. It's not protected in any way.

Comment: You seem to be fundamentally confused, `self.level` is a property, properties are *descriptors*. The way the property descriptor works is that when you *access* the property on an instance, it calls the getter, if you *assign* to the property on an instance, it calls the *setter*. If you **don't assign to the property**, how coudl the setter possibly be called?

Comment: Also, note, python doesn't really have access modifiers, ie. **everything** is public, really. A single underscore is just a naming convention to singnal that this attribute s not a part of the API and should not be used (but you can if you really want to ...)

Comment: Assigning to `_level` bypasses the setter. If it didn't, how could the setter assign to it?

Comment: IOW, how could the setter possibly be called in `self._level = level if level else 0`? The property isn't involved anywhere in that code.

Comment: You should use `0` as the default value of `level`, rather than `None`. Then you don't need the conditional in `__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Got it, I just realized the setter is never called. Thanks for pointing this out, I understand now.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps it is more obvious what is going on if instead of going with `self._level`, you just replace it with `self.foo` everywhere (just for illustration's sake, not a good name to actually use of course) and what is going on should be super obvious

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In the first block, when the attribute is protected `self._level` I realize the setter is never called. However, when I change it to public `self.level` in the second block, is it implied that it will call the setter (since the validations kick in?) This is the part that still surprises me.

Comment: *stop thinking in terms of protected private*, those aren't really things in the Python language or runtime, they are merely *naming conventions*. The issue isn't protected vs private -- again, because the runtime makes no such distinction -- it is whether you *use the propertyy or not*

Comment: I'm not sure what is surprising, if you use `self.my_property = whatever`, the the setter is called. That is *the whole point* of `property`. Try doing what I suggested above, just forget about `self._level`, rename it in your code to `self.foo`. Then look at it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you aren't using your `property` in the `__init__`, so of course, the property setter is never called!

```
self._level = level if level else 0
```

Should be:

```
self.level = level if level else 0
```

Some advice, *stop thinking in terms of "protected" vs "public"*. The Python runtime *recognizes no such thing*, there *are no access modifiers in Python*. These are merely *naming conventions*. I think this naming convention is confusing you. There is no reason why if you have

```
@property
def level(self):
    ...
```

Should modify a variable called `_level`, again, this is merely a convention. You could call it whatever you want. So, consider the following:

```
class Course:

    def __init__(self, level=None):        
        self.foo = level if level else 0
        
    @property
    def level(self):
        return self.foo
    
    @level.setter
    def level(self, value):        
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('The value of level must be of type int.')        
        if value < 0:
            self.foo = 0
        elif value > 100:
            self.foo = 100
        else:
            self.foo = value
```

This should hopefully make it more obvious why your `__init__` never actually calls the setter -- **because you don't use the property!** The property is `level`, not `foo`. Of course, you would probably never use a naming scheme like the above because it would be confusing, but it should illuminate *what is happening with your code*.

Now, it should become obvious why if we change the `__init__` to:

```
    def __init__(self, level=None):        
        self.level = level if level else 0
```

The property is called. Because `self.level` is the property, not `self.foo`. The property setters/getters will only be called if you *use the property*, which is `self.level`, not `self.foo`

Comment: I understand this writeup, but this doesn't recapitulate the phenomenon I described in my initial question. If I create four objects using the class you proposed above, the validations don't kick in (ie. it will print `[0, 10, -10, 150]`, rather than the desired `[0, 10, 0, 100]`)

Comment: @batlike **the whole point of the code above is to illustrate why the setter isn't called**. I'm not sure how else to word this. In the above, the "validation doesn't kick in" either, that is *the point I'm making*.

Comment: @batlike IOW, it is *exactly equivalent* to your first code example, and provides the exact same output

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you for taking time to respond. I know it isn't easy and I really appreciate this - I sense some frustration and so I just want to convey my gratitude. My main confusion is not in the behavior of the first block, but rather the second block. I am not fully able to understand why the validations kick in for the second block.

Comment: @batlike because you are using the property! `level` is the property not `foo` (or in your example, `_level`)

Comment: I think I understand, but may need some time to digest this. Again, thank you for taking time to write, I know you didn't have to but elected to help someone in learning. Thank you.